# What is the appropriate way to rename files to mirror sentence case?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of files who names begin with small case. I would like to rename all the files to begin with capital case. I have written small script but it actually doesn't seem to work. What could I not be doing right? How best should I go about it

```
import os

folder = "G:/Audios"


def renamefiles(directory):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file[0].islower():
            print(file)
            newfile = file[0].upper() + file[1:]
            print(newfile)
            os.rename(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.join(folder, newfile))


renamefiles(folder)
```

Comment: @moses what about the script "doesn't seem to work." ?

Comment: @devdwards the files are not renamed as desired

Comment: show us input that is not renaming as desired. Seems it's working to me, I ran your script. files named 'abc.txt', 'def.txt.' rename to 'Abc.txt', 'Def.txt' see here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/downshift/shares/946c31fe073d4a809e80c9045d3e74f7/

Comment: I tried the script in another drive it worked as desired. I think the drive I was running the script had a problem. A sample of the files in that drive were successfully renamed in the other drive.